# Gulp Command running Error in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, cmd, gulp, laravel-5.3

I am new in Laravel. I am trying to run `gulp` command in CMD to get CSS and JS (vue.js) file. I am getting following error while I am trying to run `gulp` command in CMD. I am using Laravel 5.3.

```
{ [Error: ./resources/assets/js/app.js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "add-module-exports" specified in "base" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "D:\\php7\\htdocs\\addbook\\
resources\\assets\\js" at D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:176:17
    at Array.map (native) at Function.normalisePlugins (D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:154:20)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:229:36)
    at OptionManager.init (D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:374:12)
    at File.initOptions (D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:216:65)
    at new File (D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:139:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipeline.js:46:16)
    at transpile (D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\node_modules\babel-loader\index.js:38:20)
    at Object.module.exports (D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\node_modules\babel-loader\index.js:131:12)]
  message: './resources/assets/js/app.js\nModule build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "add-module-exports" specified in "base" at 0, attempted to resolv
e relative to "D:\\\\php7\\\\htdocs\\\\addbook\\\\resources\\\\assets\\\\js"\n  at D:\\php7\\htdocs\\addbook\\node_modules\\babel-core\\lib\\transformation\\f
ile\\options\\option-manager.js:176:17\n    at Array.map (native)\n    at Function.normalisePlugins (D:\\php7\\htdocs\\addbook\\node_modules\\babel-core\\lib\\t
ransformation\\file\\options\\option-manager.js:154:20)\n    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (D:\\php7\\htdocs\\addbook\\node_modules\\babel-core\\lib\\transforma
tion\\file\\options\\option-manager.js:229:36)\n    at OptionManager.init (D:\\php7\\htdocs\\addbook\\node_modules\\babel-core\\lib\\transformation\\file\\optio
ns\\option-manager.js:374:12)\n    at File.initOptions (D:\\php7\\htdocs\\addbook\\node_modules\\babel-core\\lib\\transformation\\file\\index.js:216:65)\n    at
 new File (D:\\php7\\htdocs\\addbook\\node_modules\\babel-core\\lib\\transformation\\file\\index.js:139:24)\n    at Pipeline.transform (D:\\php7\\htdocs\\addboo
k\\node_modules\\babel-core\\lib\\transformation\\pipeline.js:46:16)\n    at transpile (D:\\php7\\htdocs\\addbook\\node_modules\\babel-loader\\index.js:38:20)\n
    at Object.module.exports (D:\\php7\\htdocs\\addbook\\node_modules\\babel-loader\\index.js:131:12)',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: true,
  plugin: 'webpack-stream',
  __safety: { toString: [Function: bound ] } }
```

Could anyone give me any solution regarding this ?

**gulpfile.js**

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue');


elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
});


elixir(function(mix) {
   mix.webpack('app.js');
}); 


elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.version(['css/app.css', 'js/app.js']);
});
```

Comment: What does your Gulpfile look like? Did you run ```npm install``` or ```npm update``` prior to running ```gulp```?

Comment: Thanks @llker Mutlu for your reply. I run `npm install` and `npm update` prior to running `gulp`. I added **gulpfile.js** in the question. Thanks

Comment: It's not a gulp issue maybe. Check you app.js file. 
Unknown plugin "add-module-exports" specified in "base" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "D:\\php7\\htdocs\\addbook\\
resources\\assets\\js".

Comment: this is more then likely a configuration issue with your module loader. show us your `app.js` and `config.js`.. are you using *express* or *webpack* in nodejs?

Comment: also, looking at that documentation.. it seems like you've done some copy and pasting..

I would consider removing `'js/app.js'` from your mix.version call here... this `js/app.js` reference is probably not for node. it's probably for a spa framework.

where as the contents of that app.js file is attempting to reference node module loading

Comment: thus `mix.webpack('app.js');` is a server app, and `js/app.js` is a client-side spa app... 

I personally use `server.js` as the file name for my node app to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

From the Laravel Docs:

> If you are developing on a Windows system or you are running your VM
>   on a Windows host system, you may need to run the npm install command
>   with the --no-bin-links switch enabled:
>
> `npm install --no-bin-links`

[Laravel Docs: Elixir Installation and Setup](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir#installation)

Remove `/node_modules` and run `npm install` with the `--no-bin-links` switch like mentioned in the docs and quoted above.

Comment: Thanks @llker Mutlu. I uninstall `node` and install it again as per your instruction. I installed again `gulp` also. But I am getting the previous error again. Thanks